# Parse Spanish characters in Objective-C using NSXmlParser

Tags: objective-c

I am using NSXmlParser

I fetch all the data from server, but parsing do not end, because of the Spanish characters in the data. How do I completely parse these Spanish words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the encoding of the document is correct?  What encoding does it use?  Does it include `encoding="UTF-8"` or some such in the `<?xml ... ?>` header?

If the XML parser doesn't know the encoding, or the encoding has been incorrectly specified, then it will fail to parse.

If these are encoded as XML entities, are the entities HEX-encoded, or named?  If they are named, they will need to be included in the DTD and you'll need to call `setShouldResolveExternalEntities:` with `YES`.